# Handlebars with whitespace inside throwing a Missing Helper error

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, handlebars.js

I am using handlebars 4.x in my node application which is accepting dynamic content with handlebars in it. On compiling the handlebars, I am getting a `Missing helper...` error in case the handlebars have a whitespace in it.

For example: `{{first name}}` throws a `Missing helper first` error.

Ideally, it should ignore the handlebar if no match or helper found, but even if it matches it against an empty value, that'd do the job for me because right now, it's breaking the application.

I wonder why handlebars hasn't inherently handled this error.

Now, since this content is dynamic, I cannot handle this case easily.

I am using the following regex to manually escape any handlebars I am not compiling against: `{{[^\n}]+}}`

I am looking for an inbuilt handlebars solution if there exists any which takes care of this problem for me.

Comment: When something like this `{{first name}}` is found, Handlebars consider `first` as a helper. See their plugin guide to understand. So, use keys without spaces in it or use _ instead of space.

Comment: That doesn't solve my problem. I just mentioned above that the content I am receiving is from the client side so I have no control over it. I need a better error handling case for this.

Comment: @AkshayKhetrapal i guess you'll have to make sure the handlebars expressions are correct before you pass the source to handlebars.

Comment: Have your tried this `{{[first name]}}`?